# time does not match format '%a %b %d %H:

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I get this error while trying to use datetime module

It seems that it does not recognize my time format

The time format that is used in the file is like this:

Sat Jan 17 21:20:41 +0000 2015

Does anybody know what causes this problem? Thanks!

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttrends.py", line 46, in <module>
    week = time_str_to_weekday(time_str, parse_time_format=parse_time_format)
  File "ttrends.py", line 36, in time_str_to_weekday
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_str, parse_time_format)))
  File "c:\python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 494, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "c:\python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='time.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>" does not match format '%a %b %d %H:
%M:%S +0000 %Y'
```

```html
parse_time_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'
day_output_date_format = '%Y%m%d_%a'
month_output_date_format = '%Y%m'
week_output_date_format = '%Y_%U'

import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open("time.txt",'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    time_str = str(f)

def time_str_to_day(time_str):

    t = time.strptime(time_str, parse_time_format)

    return time.strftime(day_output_date_format, t)

def time_str_to_month(time_str):

    t = time.strptime(time_str, parse_time_format)

    return time.strftime(month_output_date_format, t)

def time_str_to_week(time_str, parse_time_format=parse_time_format):

    t = time.strptime(time_str, parse_time_format)

    return time.strftime(week_output_date_format, t)

#week starts on Monday
def time_str_to_weekday(time_str, parse_time_format=parse_time_format):
     dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_str, parse_time_format)))

     week = []
     start = dt - timedelta(days = dt.weekday())

     for i in range(7):
         current = start + timedelta(days = i)
         week.append(current.strftime(day_output_date_format))
     #end = start + timedelta(days = 6)
     return week
week = time_str_to_weekday(time_str, parse_time_format=parse_time_format)
print (week)
```

Comment: See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the instruction `time_str = str(f)` is transforming the object f into a str. So in your case the value of time_str is <_io.TextIOWrapper name='time.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>

You probably wanted to read the file instead :

```
time_str = f.readline()
```

Comment: Thanx @Dav It fixed that issue but now it gives this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttrends.py", line 46, in <module>
    week = time_str_to_weekday(time_str, parse_time_format=parse_time_format)
  File "ttrends.py", line 36, in time_str_to_weekday
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_str, parse_time_format)))
  File "c:\python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 494, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "c:\python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: `